# Estou criando um jogo das três pistas porém não consigo ir para próxima pergunta

Tags: c

Salve salve galera, tudo jóia com vocês? Espero que sim, tenho esse código em `C` ele está ok, mas estou tentando implementar mais perguntas e não consigo.

Segue o código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
main()
{
    int n,pts=0;
    char resposta[100];
    printf("====Jogo das Tres Pista====\n\n");
    printf("1-Inicia jogo\n\n");
    printf("2-Creditos \n\n");
    printf("3-sair\n\n");
    printf("Digite sua Opcao");
    scanf("%i",&n);
    system("cls");
    switch(n)
    {
        case 1:
        printf ("Torres: ");
        scanf ("%s", &resposta);
        printf("PALAVRA DIGITADA: %s\n\n", resposta);
        if(!strcmp(resposta, "EUA")||!strcmp(resposta, "Eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "EstadoUnido")){
            printf("Resposta Certa!, 10 pts!\n"); pts+=10;
            return 0;
        }else{
            printf("\n VOCE ERRO A PROXIMA DICA E DOLAR!, 0 pts \n\n!\n");
        }
        printf ("DOLAR: ");
        scanf ("%s", &resposta);
        printf("PALAVRA DIGITADA: %s", resposta);
        if(!strcmp(resposta, "EUA")||!strcmp(resposta, "Eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "EstadoUnido")){
            printf("Resposta Certa!, 5 pts!\n"); pts+=5;
            return 0;
        }else{
            printf("\n VOCE ERRO A PROXIMA DICA E HOLLYWOOD!, 0 pts \n\n!\n");
        }
        printf ("HOLLYWOOD!: ");
        scanf ("%s", &resposta);
        printf("PALAVRA DIGITADA: %s", resposta);
        if(!strcmp(resposta, "EUA")||!strcmp(resposta, "Eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "EstadoUnido")){
            printf("Resposta Certa!, 2 pts!\n"); pts+=2;
        }else{
            printf("\n VOCE ERRO RESPOSTA CERTA SERIA EUA VAMOS EM FRENTE!, 0 pts \n\n!\n");
        }
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        case 2:
        printf("*** CREDITOS ***\n\n BY: <<< GEOVANI >>>\n\n");
        break;
        case 3:
        printf("*** ACABOU O JOGO ***\n\n");
        break;
        default:
        printf("*** Obrigado por usa nosso sistema ***\n");
    }
}
```

alguém sabe me dizer como faço para ir para próxima pergunta sem fecha o programa

Comment: O que faz terminar é o `return 0;` que tem no `if` da resposta. É só retirar mesmo, alias eu pergunto até qual era a sua intenção ao colocar esse `return 0;` dentro do `if` ?

Answer (score 0):

O programa fecha porque você faz return 0 depois do if.
Acho que o que você pretendia era :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>


int main()
{
  int n,pts=0;
  char resposta[100];
  printf("====Jogo das Tres Pista====\n\n");
  printf("1-Inicia jogo\n\n");
  printf("2-Creditos \n\n");
  printf("3-sair\n\n");
  printf("Digite sua Opcao");
  scanf("%i",&n);
  system("cls");
  switch(n)
  {
    case 1:
    printf ("Torres: ");
    scanf ("%s", &resposta);
    printf("PALAVRA DIGITADA: %s\n\n", resposta);
    if(!strcmp(resposta, "EUA")||!strcmp(resposta, "Eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "EstadoUnido")){
        printf("Resposta Certa!, 10 pts!\n"); pts+=10;
        //return 0;//return ternmina o programa
    }else{
        printf("\n VOCE ERRO A PROXIMA DICA E DOLAR!, 0 pts \n\n!\n");
    }
    printf ("DOLAR: ");
    scanf ("%s", &resposta);
    printf("PALAVRA DIGITADA: %s", resposta);
    if(!strcmp(resposta, "EUA")||!strcmp(resposta, "Eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "EstadoUnido")){
        printf("Resposta Certa!, 5 pts!\n"); pts+=5;
        //return 0;
    }else{
        printf("\n VOCE ERRO A PROXIMA DICA E HOLLYWOOD!, 0 pts \n\n!\n");
    }
    printf ("HOLLYWOOD!: ");
    scanf ("%s", &resposta);
    printf("PALAVRA DIGITADA: %s", resposta);
    if(!strcmp(resposta, "EUA")||!strcmp(resposta, "Eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "EstadoUnido")){
        printf("Resposta Certa!, 2 pts!\n"); pts+=2;
    }else{
        printf("\n VOCE ERRO RESPOSTA CERTA SERIA EUA VAMOS EM FRENTE!, 0 pts \n\n!\n");
    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    case 2:
    printf("*** CREDITOS ***\n\n BY: <<< GEOVANI >>>\n\n");
    break;
    case 3:
    printf("*** ACABOU O JOGO ***\n\n");
    break;
    default:
    printf("*** Obrigado por usa nosso sistema ***\n");
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

usar tantos if else no jogo vai deixar bem confuso, mas seguindo o sistema que voce ta usando seria abaixo do VOCE ERRO RESPOSTA CERTA...

seria melhor voce chamar um novo quando o usuario escolher INICIAR JOGO que contem as perguntas, de uma forma simplista voce faria varias copias dele e so alterava as respostas
tipo

case 1:
Pergunta1();
Pergunta2();
Pergunta3();

assim ele faria uma pergunta depois da outra
ai faria as perguntas assim

```
Pergunta1(){
    printf ("Torres: ");
    scanf ("%s", &resposta);
    printf("PALAVRA DIGITADA: %s\n\n", resposta);
    if(!strcmp(resposta, "EUA")||!strcmp(resposta, "Eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "EstadoUnido")){
        printf("Resposta Certa!, 10 pts!\n"); pts+=10;
        return 0;
    }else{
        printf("\n VOCE ERRO A PROXIMA DICA E DOLAR!, 0 pts \n\n!\n");
    }
    printf ("DOLAR: ");
    scanf ("%s", &resposta);
    printf("PALAVRA DIGITADA: %s", resposta);
    if(!strcmp(resposta, "EUA")||!strcmp(resposta, "Eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "EstadoUnido")){
        printf("Resposta Certa!, 5 pts!\n"); pts+=5;
        return 0;
    }else{
        printf("\n VOCE ERRO A PROXIMA DICA E HOLLYWOOD!, 0 pts \n\n!\n");
    }
    printf ("HOLLYWOOD!: ");
    scanf ("%s", &resposta);
    printf("PALAVRA DIGITADA: %s", resposta);
    if(!strcmp(resposta, "EUA")||!strcmp(resposta, "Eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "eua")||!strcmp(resposta, "EstadoUnido")){
        printf("Resposta Certa!, 2 pts!\n"); pts+=2;
    }else{
        printf("\n VOCE ERRO RESPOSTA CERTA SERIA EUA VAMOS EM FRENTE!, 0 pts \n\n!\n");
    }}
```